# New column with values 1/0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe having one column of my interest:

```
Col1   
code 
goal
python
detail
```

I would like to create a new column, Col2 having values 1 or 0 depending on rows' value in Col1; specifically:

- if a row has a value in the list `my_list=['goal', 'detail', 'objective']`, then assign 1;
- if it has not, then assign 0.

My output would be:

```
Col1       Col2
code        0
goal        1
python      0
detail      1
```

I tried

```
# set default value
df['Col2'] = 0

# update according to conditions
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.contains('goal'), 'Col2'] = 1
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.contains('detail'), 'Col2'] = 1
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.contains('objective'), 'Col2'] = 1
```

but this seems to be partially wrong.
I think I should use apply and consider word x in `my_list` rather than doing manually (it would be difficult in case of many, many!, values in the list).

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` + `Series.isin`

```
import numpy as np

my_list=['goal', 'detail', 'objective']

df['Col2'] = np.where(df.Col1.isin(my_list), 1, 0)
```

or as mentioned by @Ch3steR

```
df['Col2'] = df.Col1.isin(my_list).astype('int')
```

---

```
     Col1  Col2
0   code      0
1    goal     1
2  python     0
3  detail     1
```

Comment: Thank you Sushanth! I was pretty sure there was a better way to do it :) I am marking your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: `df['Col2'] = df.Col1.isin(my_list).astype('int')`?

Comment: Glad to have helped @LucaDiMauro

Comment: @Sushanth Coming from `C` 1 is `True` and 0 is `False` hehe...Nice answer tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['code', 'goal', 'python', 'detail'], columns = ['Col1'])

mylist=['goal', 'detail', 'objective']

df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda cell: 1 if cell in mylist else 0)
```

gives

```
     Col1  Col2
0    code     0
1    goal     1
2  python     0
3  detail     1
```